# edge throwing post 405 error..But not chrome and safari

Tags: java, google-chrome, internet-explorer, post, submit

I'm using Spring MVC application

The web application is created and working fine in chrome browser and safari. While checking with edge browser its throwing 405 post error where I'm using form submission and ajax functions.

Is it configuration related error or?

Comment: What's the Edge browser version? Try to use Edge browser F12 developer tools to check the response Allow methods, whether the server side allow the related method. Besides, if the server side allows the method, perhaps the issue is related to the client side, try to [reset the Edge browser](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10).

Comment: Thanks for your command...The problem was i set audio in jquery..But in html inside of audio tag [src=' '] was empty...so the form was loaded again and again and the data lost happend...

Comment: Have you ever tried to debug your JQuery code, it seems that the issue is related to this part and cannot get the audio source. Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).